# Mount fstab cifs guest command not recognized

Tags: fstab, shared-folders, cifs

During the last few days I've tried to connect to a Windows shared folder on another machine using Ubuntu.

Finally yesterday I succeeded, but today it is not working anymore. 
Here's what I have done:

- create a directory on Desktop
- add this line to /etc/fstab:

  ```
  //network_ip/shared_folder /home/user_name/Desktop/directory_on_Desktop cifs guest,uid=1000 0 0
  ```

Yesterday it worked fine, but today it says: `mount (22): invalid argument`

If I change, in the fstab file, from `guest` to `users` it works fine. But why can't I use guest?

P.S. Yesterday after finishing using the PC I shut it down without manually unmounting the shared folder. While it was shutting down it stopped on the Ubuntu window (the one with five dots under the logo) so I held down the power button to shut it down.

Comment: This is an old entry, but you can try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/199142/cifs-shares-not-mounting-after-modifying-etc-fstab

Comment: Unfortunately if I add users it still doesn’t work (it says invalid argument), the only way to make it work is removing guest.

Answer (score 0):

1) perhaps, just a hunch, fstab program runs before network is up.
The correct approach should be editing /etc/network/if-up.d  for updating the fstab whenever the interface goes up (and if-down.d, when it goes down). (ask for help with this)

2) Other thing: probably you had the guest user, if you want only the "guest" user to mount, ok, but you'll probably want any user to mount. you should put "user", for any user to have access.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write that the error: mount (22): invalid argument appears when I do: sudo mount - a. So I think that the problem is not in your point number one (tell me if I am wrong). In addition to that I put guest just because I don't want to be asked for password (because there isn't one).

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the same behavior in Arch, mount.cifs version 6.7. Whenever the `guest` option was specified the mount command failed with the "invalid agrument" message, even though the man pages listed the `guest` option as supported.

I worked around that by specifying `username=guest,password=` instead. That is, user "guest", empty password. Worked fine connecting to an anonymous share on a Windows XP laptop. I think you can use any name in this case, not just "guest". Maybe even an empty name will work.